# Scanner needs entry to be entered twice

Tags: java, error-handling

I did see other questions like mine but my program was quite different so I couldn't figure out the problem. Basically, when I'm asked to enter code using this program, it needs to be entered twice. I can't figure out why.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing.

```
package prac4;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintNums {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number=1;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What number should I count to?");

    while (sc.nextInt()<0){
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: ");
        if(sc.nextInt()>0){
        number = sc.nextInt();
    }
        }
    number = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();


    System.out.println(number);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `sc.nextInt()` program hangs and waits for your input. You need to call `sc.nextInt()` only once and assign `number` only once per cycle and then check your condition:

```
    while ((number = sc.nextInt()) < 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: ");
    }
    System.out.println(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are asking input 2 times (sc.nextInt()), so if you want to get the value once you should call sc.nextInt() once. you can change the snippet like below.

```
package prac4;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintNums {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int number=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("What number should I count to?");

while (number<0){
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer: ");

    number = sc.nextInt();
}

sc.close();


System.out.println(number);
}
}
```

Comment: I didn't see the above solution, I would prefer above one